# Does Jammit support selective compression?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, jammit

In my assets.yml, I have several packages for jammit (PC, SP, FP...) I just wanna compress SP and FP packages and keep the pc for original. Could we do this in jammit?

Comment: This would interest me as well. Have you figured it out yet?